# Jenkins can't open make

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I have recently installed Jenkins 2.89.2 on Ubuntu 17.10 and I am trying to set up my first project. So far I've managed to get Jenkins to download the source code from my repository but I'm having trouble calling make. I configured to call make in the Project > Configure > Build Environment > Build (Execute Shell) with the command `make`. After calling make it returns the error `make: not found`.

I have tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199123/command-not-found-from-jenkins-execute-shell) to related questions below relating to adding the correct directory to the $PATH environment variable. I have tried adding it to the system settings under Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Environment variables, as well as under Project > Configure > Build Environment > Build (Execute Shell), setting PATH to `$PATH:/usr/bin`. I was sure that I managed to set the Path correctly, as I was echoing $PATH before calling but then tried calling make with its fully qualified path which resulted in the same error: `sh: /usr/bin/make: not found`. Which leads me to believe I am not calling make correctly.

I experimented calling make with the command `sh make` and `sh /usr/bin/make` and the error changed to `Can't open make` and `Can't open /usr/bin/make`

This lead me to believe the access rights to make were incorrect, but it seems that it is.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 222792 Feb  1  2017 /usr/bin/make
```

Perhaps the jenkins user needs to be added a group?

I'm running out of ideas on what it could be and doubt if I come to the right conclusion about the way I am calling make.

Some other details:
make works correctly at the command line
`which make` returns `/usr/bin/make`

I hereby declare my allegiance to [Koalemos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koalemos) and ask the gods of Jenkins to have mercy on my soul.

Comment: I've even tried following the tutorial in https://github.com/jbankes/Hello_Jenkins to the letter and even that fails when make is called. Looks like I'm missing something in the installation of Jenkins. I followed these [instructions](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu) to install:

Comment: Since posting I tried installing Jenkins on Ubuntu 16.04 and this doesn't have any trouble executing make. I'm guessing there's something in the Ubuntu 17.10 installation of Jenkins that it doesn't like. The permissions on the make executable are the same `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 207528 Feb 15  2016 /usr/bin/make`

Comment: The paths of the Jenkins install are vastly different between 17.10 and 16.04. For example, the home directory is `/var/snap/jenkins/6` while on 16.04 is `/var/lib/jenkins`. Found this about [snap](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy) in Ubuntu. Tried installing jenkins via snap on 17.10 but Jenkins wasn't able to run as a service.  I'm giving up trying to solve this. I'm declaring it "broken" :-) Back to Ubuntu 16.04 for me! That will teach me that the latest and greatest is not always the best.

Comment: Actually, it does install as a service. The result is the same if installed via snap.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using the Jenkins docker image, note that the image provided by Jenkins does not include this (make) along with other deps you may need.

What you can do is run a docker exec against that container with the user of root, and install all the deps with apt-get and then your build will run.

```
docker-machine env jenkins
#paste the env to set the docker-machine context
docker exec -it --user root <container-name> /bin/bash 
#terminal session as root starts
apt-get update 
apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: The correct name of the package is "build-essential".